# Деревья: узлы и глубина

Tags: дерево, c++

У меня задание заполнить дерево целыми числами вручную.По заданным значениям "х" рассчитать число всех узлов с глубиной "х" в заданном дереве.

Вот я по псевдокоду:

```
функция сумма(узел, глубина)
    если глубина = 0 то   // достигли нужной глубины
        возвращаем значение узла
    иначе                 // не достигли, нужно идти глубже
        возвращаем сумма(левый потомок, глубина - 1) + сумма(правый потомок, глубина - 1)
```

Написала код. Функция Sum у меня. Оно компилируется, но программа еще не выполняет условие. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. И я еще изменила функцию добавления узла, как мистер [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) писал ранее. Мне нужно именно по заданным значениям "х" рассчитать число всех узлов с глубиной "х" в заданном дереве, а моя функция сум что-то вообще непонятное делает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
   int x; 
   Node *l,*r;
};

void show(Node *&Tree) 
{
    if (Tree!=NULL)
    {
       show(Tree->l); 
       cout<<Tree->x; 
       show(Tree->r); 
    }
}

void add_node(int x,Node *&MyTree) 
 {
    if (MyTree) 
    {
   if (x < MyTree->x)
      add_node(x, MyTree->l);
   else
      add_node(x, MyTree->r); 
 } else {
    MyTree=new Node; 
    MyTree->x=x; 
    MyTree->l=MyTree->r=NULL; 
 }
}
int sum (Node *&Tree,int x)
{
    if (Tree==NULL) 
    return 1;
    else
    {

        for (int i=0;i<x;++i) 
        (sum(Tree->l,--x)+ sum(Tree->r,--x));
         return (sum(Tree->l,--x)+ sum(Tree->r,--x));

    }

}
void DeleteTree(Node *Tree)
{
     if (Tree)
     {
           DeleteTree(Tree->l);
           DeleteTree(Tree->r);
           delete Tree;
           Tree = NULL;
     }
}
int main()
{
   Node *Tree=NULL;  
  int z,k;
  cin >> z;
      for (int i=0;i<z;i++) 
      {
          cin >> k;
          add_node(k,Tree);
      }
      show(Tree);
      DeleteTree(Tree);
      cin.get();
      getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: выделите код программы и нажмите "{}" дабы код выглядел по человечески...
[http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading11][1]

а то сейчас нечитабельно...


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading11

Comment: Хм.

    cout << vvedite n;

А этот код у вас компилируется?

Comment: Не компилируется. Там ошибок куча..я не особо развита в программировании( по этому и прошу помощи.

Comment: может вы всё же разберётесь с простыми ошибками сами? 

просто тут(хешкод) запрещена "работа за автора", да что толку если я за вас решу все ошибки? правильно вы от этого умнее не станете...


вы поищите в интернете описание ваших ошибок и решите их, а те что непонятны уже отпишите тут, и тогда вам нормально помогут...

----------------------------

пока я вижу такие ошибки

    1.в main нету n! (будет ошибка)
    2.у вас одни функция InsRec с 3-мя параметрами, а вызываете её вы с 1-м или 2-мя!
    3.у вас не только куча ошибок но и ничерта неделающий код...

Comment: вот почитайте: ["Работа со структурами данных в языках Си и Python"][1] может что прояснится (ибо код нужно делать с нуля!) 


  [1]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-data_structures_01/

Comment: Переделала с нуля. Посмотрите пожалуйста. тут только само дерево.

Comment: в функции `add_node(k,tree)` у вас неправильно работает добавление в дерево при (tree==NULL) она должна выполнить только первый if не выполняя остальные

исправив это можно значительно упростить `add_node()`

Comment: Наверное сами уже сделали, но на всякий случай IMHO `add_node()` проще всего записать так

     if (Mytree) {
       if (x < Mytree->)
          add_node(x, Mytree->l);
       else
          add_node(x, Mytree->r); // x == Mytree-> пойдет сюда
     } else {
        MyTree=new Node; 
        MyTree->x=x; 
        MyTree->l=MyTree->r=NULL; 
     }

в DeleteTree()

     Tree = NULL;

можно выбросить, а в `show()` можно попечатать еще и адреса

     cout << Tree->x << " [" << Tree << " left: " << Tree->l << " right: " << Tree->r << "]\n";

Answer (score 4):

Начну, пожалуй, с самого очевидного: **не пытайтесь программировать на языке, которого не знаете**. Я, конечно, понимаю, универ, лабы, препод подгоняет. Но прежде чем что-то писать, нужно понять хотя бы основы языка. Вы же, судя по вашему коду, даже основы понимаете очень смутно. Поэтому берите учебник (Керниган и Ритчи, Дейтел, да кто угодно, кроме, пожалуй, Шилдта), читайте его с самого начала, выполняйте упражения.

Помогать вам дописывать вашу программу я не стану. Во-первых, для того чтобы ваша программа хотя бы скомпилировалась, нужно половину кода переписать. Во-вторых, если я напишу за вас код, вы скорее всего просто скопируете его, не потрудившись понять, как он работает и в чём были ваши ошибки. Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, а вы можете быть добросовестным учеником, но, исходя из моего опыта на этом ресурсе вероятность такого исхода крайне мала.

Впрочем, для того, чтобы вы поняли, какой же бред вы написали, я пройдусь по самым явным вашим ошибкам, и прокомментирую их.

Итак, функция `main()`.

```
tree* InsRec( &n);
```

Три ошибки в одной строке. Я полагаю, что этой строкой вы пытались создать дерево. Во-первых, переменную `n` вы нигде не объявляли, но пытаетесь не просто её использовать, но и взять её адрес. Во-вторых, функция `InsRec` принимает три параметра, вы же передаёте ей только один. В третьих, сама по себе эта строка является объявлением сигнатуры функции (а не переменной, как вы, скорее всего, надеялись).

```
cout << vvedite n;
```

`vvedite n` нужно взять в кавычки. Без кавычек компилятор посчитает, что `vvedite` и `n` это переменные, и выдаст ошибки. Во-первых, потому что ни одна из них не объявлена. Во-вторых, потому что с точки зрения синтаксиса C/C++ конструкция вида `переменная _пробел_ переменная` является форменным бредом.

Теперь про функцию `InsRec`.

```
tree* InsRec(tree *root, node data, int **n)
```

Не совсем понятно, для чего нужен указатель на указатель в качестве третьего параметра. Обычно на переменные такого типа вешают двумерные массивы, вы же почему-то пытаетесь использовать её как верхнюю границу для цикла:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Чтобы вы поняли всю бредовость этой строки, попробуйте посчитать от единицы до матрицы.

```
strcpy(root->data.value, data.value);
```

Вы пытаетесь использовать функцию `strcpy`, но не подключаете библиотеку, в которой она объявлена.

```
root->left=InsRec(root->left,data);
```

и

```
root->right=InsRec(root->right, data);
```

Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию `InsRec`, передав ей два параметра, хотя объявили её как функцию от трёх переменных. Вы что, до C++ на JavaScript писали? Возможно, если убрать третий параметр, объявить и инициализировть где-нибудь переменную `n`, то это будет больше похоже на вставку узла в дерево.

В общем, садитесь за учебники, учите основы, и только после этого пытайтесь что-то писать.

Comment: подписываюсь под всем выше сказанным:) берите учебник и читайте с нуля!

Comment: Переделала с нуля, как вы сказали. Посмотрите пожалуйста..Тут только дерево. само задание я еще не сделала.

Comment: Гораздо лучше. Отладчика под рукой у меня нет, поэтому точно сказать не могу, но с виду дерево строится правильно (при условии, что это простое несбалансированное бинарное дерево, в которм правый потомок всегда больше, а левый - меньше родителя). Единственное замечание - в ваше дерево нельзя добавить два одинаковых элемента. Если это так и надо - хорошо, пробуйте выполнить задание. Ничего сложного там быть не должно, нужно поиском в глубину рекурсивно спуститься на нужный уровень дерева и прибавить к текущей сумме значение узла.

Comment: Дерево бинарное несбалансированное по условию задания. На счет двух одинаковых элементов я не знаю. В задание ничего не говорят. Наверное нужно,чтобы одинаковые тоже можно было писать туда. Сейчас попробую само задание осилить.

Comment: пока ненадо реализовывать 2 значения с одним ключом ... (сначала это доделайте)

Comment: @fori1ton, Вы пишете

     не пытайтесь программировать на языке, которого не знаете

вроде бы верно. Но посмотрите, какой прогресс мы видим **всего за 3 часа**. Код просто изменился на глазах. 

--

Интересно, можно ли за это время изучить С++ по книжкам (как положено) или на самом деле обучение "на примерах" (подозреваю, что  ТС посмотрела несколько программок за час-другой) столь эффективно?

Comment: Мне помогали. Я пошла к учителю и он помог мне написать само дерево. Но писала лично я. Но само задание я все еще не знаю как сделать. Вот сижу, но пока еще не нашла решение проблемы.

Comment: Тут ничего сложного нет. Нужно перебирать узлы дерева поиском в глубину. На каждом шаге запоминать текущую глубину и сумму. Если глубина меньше заданного уровня - идём глубже, если равна - возвращаем значение угла. Вот примерный псевдокод:

    функция сумма(узел, глубина)
        если глубина = 0 то   // достигли нужной глубины
            возвращаем значение узла
        иначе                 // не достигли, нужно идти глубже
            возвращаем сумма(левый потомок, глубина - 1) + сумма(правый потомок, глубина - 1)

Почитайте про поиск (обход дерева) в глубину, возможно, станет понятнее.

Comment: Наверное все-таки надо возвращать 1, если достигли заданной глубины и 0, если функция `сумма()` вызвана с `узел == NULL`, независимо от глубины.

Ведь требуется подсчитать **число узлов** на заданной глубине, не так ли?

Comment: Да, действительно. Невнимательно прочёл задачу. Впрочем, смысл от этого не сильно меняется, да и затрагивать в псевдокоде все детали реализации (вроде проверок на NULL) особого смысла нет.

Comment: @Lera_E, так и сделали бы точно по заданию 2 функции

    void sumx (Node *tree, int x[], int nx) {
       for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
          cout << "level: " << x[i] << ' ' << cntx(tree, x[i]) << "Nodes\n";
    }

функция `cntx()` в соответствии с псевдокодом

    int cntx (Node *tree, int deep) {
       if (!tree || deep < 0) return 0; // нет такой глубины в этой ветке
       if (deep == 0) return 1; // узел на заданной глубине
       return cntx(tree->l, --deep) + cntx(tree->r, --deep);
    }

Обратите внимание в `sumx()` передаем (из `main`) массив заданных "глубин" из `nx` элементов

Comment: Спасибо. НО у меня все таки есть вопрос по поводу вот этого:
"в sumx() передаем (из main) массив заданных "глубин" из nx элементов." Это я если честно не до конца поняла..У нас есть функция "меин" в которой мы вызываем остальные функции,а также в ней реализован цикл заполнения дерева. Но как мне из функции меин передать массив глубин xn, если все мои звенья дерева перешли в функцию add_node. То есть мой вопрос вот в чем:
Как передается в sumx() из меин массив глубин из nx элементов. простите, если вопрос глупый.

Comment: IMHO лучше вызвать между `show()` и `DeleteTree()`.

    int main () {
       ....
       show(Tree);
       int levels[3] = {1, 3, 5}; // это для простоты, может Вы захотите с клавиатуры их ввести? и не 3 а больше...
       sumx(Tree, levels, 3);
       DeleteTree(Tree);
       ....
    }

Видится что-то в таком духе.

*(похоже, это мой последний комментарий здесь. Лимит-с).*